# No autocomplete on cocapods for AppCode 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, cocoapods, appcode

I have recently set up a project from a base XCode Project with the cocoapods installation, and when importing the project into AppCode 3.1, I am not getting any autocompletion for my swift frameworks that are installed through CocoaPods

Here is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :osx, '10.10'
use_frameworks!

target 'Main' do
    pod "SwiftyJSON", ">= 2.1.3"
    pod 'BrightFutures', '~> 1.0.0-beta.3'
end

target 'MainTests' do

end
```

As you can see, I have 2 pods defined (one is SwiftyJson and one is BrightFutures). Both of these pods are installed as Swift Frameworks (hence why `use_frameworks!`) is there.

Everything appears to be imported and working correctly for AppCode (I have two projects, one is the main project, and the other one is Pods, which is the exact same as it is in XCode), however it appears that AppCode doesn't index any of the Pod frameworks, so I am not getting autocompletion status on using those frameworks, at all. As an example, in the following code

```
import Cocoa
import BrightFutures

@NSApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {



    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        let f = future { 5 }.map{f in f + 7}

        f.onSuccess{callback in println(callback)}
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

I get no autocompletion on the following

- `import BrightFutures` (importing anything else that isn't from CocoaPods works fine)
- Auto complete on anything on this line `let f = future { 5 }.map{f in f + 7}` or this one `f.onSuccess{callback in println(callback)}`

Autocomplete works fine on anything else (i.e. `aNotification`) which is an argument on the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function

Is there some setting in AppCode that I am missing, or is this something that hasn't been implemented yet? In XCode, autocompletion works completely correctly.

EDIT: I have also noticed that in AppCode, the .framework files are in red (not sure if this means anything?)

Comment: I would create ticket on AppCode bug tracker. Sorry for off-topic

Comment: Already have, will see where it goes https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11836